# Issues with signing up with username using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've set up a rails app which uses `devise` as the authentication gem. However, I wanted the user to choose a random user name and not be tied down to sharing his/her email with me. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address). However, the issue is that whenever I try to signup using a username (with an empty user database) the form shows the error `username is invalid`. For reference here are the validations that I'm runnning:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :username, :uniqueness =>{
              :case_sensitive => false
            }, presence: true
```

I don't know how to get around this issue. Any help would be really nice.

Edit: In order to give a more complete picture of the situation here's the server log when signing up:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-02-11 14:29:55 +0530

Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mM1N0AgxfoqXz4448EgHoSYz03Hdr3nX/WH1f+siRP/26VNWz4VS5lJ2I4NJjXcucgWxFvgIyON+7zwFXAESgw==", "user"=>{"username"=>"ankit0912", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('ankit0912') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Thanks.

Edit2: Users_Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.order(:karma :desc).limit(25)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user = @user.update(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Record Updated"
    else
      redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @user.id
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you give us the controller's part?

Comment: @Minato: [here](http://pastebin.com/QLq1dXku) it is. This is the controller that I've written, the auth part is handled by devise, which I do not have access to.

Comment: Pastebin doesn't work for me... please post here...

Answer (score 0):

The validation code is okay according to rails guide. Please check whether the user name param is going to the controller. If the param goes empty, the presence true validation fails and may give that error.

Also see whether the sanitized attributes are correctly defined in application controller for username.(Devise)

Comment: I just checked what you said, but to no avail. The error still persists. The error is not with the presence validation, but with the username validation.